# Graph of Android API distribution over time?

Tags: android-versions

Google of course provides their [snapshot of the current API situation](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). I'm curious to know if there is somewhere published a line graph showing the distributions and their change over time.

Comment: hm there is a better graph in the Google I/O android videos, I would like to find it. It shows the snapshots pies as larger and larger pies over time as the # of android devices increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [site](http://www.bidouille.org/misc/androidcharts) that automatically updates to the latest data from the **android.com Dashboard**, and which has three graphs showing different aspects of it.

Answer (score 3):

There is this graph from over at wikipedia, which uses the data from Google's dashboard.

[image: Graph of android versons]

Comment: This graph, while being nice, is much less up to date than the one found using @Hendrik's answer.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez - It was up to date at the time I made this answer (and for almost another year past then), thought it seems that the creator of this graph is no longer maintaining it.

Comment: @Compro01 oh! the relentless march of progress